# Insert element object into a subelement

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to insert element object found with "for loop" and .iter() in ElementTree, however I do not think it is possible and I would need to convert that element object into something else. Not sure how?

```
for child in root.iter('FinEntryLine'):
    ET.SubElement(glentry, child)
```

"glentry" is previously prepared subelement tag with a static data attributes and text, so now I want to add an element from for loop of a parsed xml file.

Comment: The seconds argument in SubElement call should be a string. You can call it like this `SubElement(glentry,'name_of_the_child',child_attributes_dict)'` .See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L442

Comment: `glentry.append(child)` should work. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append

Comment: Yep mzjn, this is working, thanks